# How to get user information for specific events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

We have set up Google Analytics on [Requestly Pricing Page](https://app.requestly.in/pricing). We  are already getting site-related information, anonymous statistics, events from the page like

- Pricing Page viewed
- Coupon Applied Successfully
- Duration Changed to Monthly
- Premium plan bought
- .. so on ..

However, Now we want to track the users who are performing a specific event like

- Pricing Page Viewed

but did not purchase premium plan So that we can send targetted emails to those users. If we can get the user IDs (non PII data) from Google Analytics for a particular event, we can map them from our CRM system and get their emails and send them an email.

So, How can we get the list of users associated with some event?

Comment: You can trace the userId when the user enters his email address to send it to a form, if you don't have that information I don't see how you can send him an email.

Comment: I already have a userID and email in my CRM system. I am looking for a way to integrate both the systems such that I can extract userIDs from a specific event and take an action - Email them for an example

Comment: Are you sending the userId to Analytics?

Comment: @Michele Yes we have started sending User Ids to Analytics and now we are able to see User performing events in User explorer but I would like a reverse way. Given an event I want to know which users performed that event.

Comment: With the information you provided I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the information to Google Analytics as a custom dimension, simply add the second dimension in the Event report.

If you are sending the userId with its defined parameter you have to enable User-ID in your Property and create a User-ID view to see the data in your Analytics reports: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

> Yes we have started sending User Ids to Analytics and now we are able to see User performing events in User explorer but I would like a reverse way. Given an event I want to know which users performed that event.

### User ID in Google Analytics

There are three ways to import the User ID in Google Analytics:

1. customizing the [schema field](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4565987?hl=en) `userId`
2. setting up a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) which contains the value
3. both of the above

In case 1, you can access the data via Google Analytics in User Explorer report, setting up a [User ID View](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123669?hl=en).

In case 2, you can access the data in each report that allows to define a [secondary dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6175970?hl=en).

In both cases, you can access the data in Google BigQuery, if you set up the [export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en).

### About your specific need

To know which users performed a specific event I suggest you to create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033013?hl=en) in which you specify the event in the filters and you set your User ID custom dimension as dimension. This approach of course assumes that you import the User ID at least as a custom dimension.